# Indent only in second line in paragraph in rich text box (c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How can I make indent only in the second row, to be space under the first word of paragraph.
as this:
[image]

Comment: This Hebrew text formatting, and I write a word processor to design a Hebrew text

Comment: Well good luck :) sorry couldn't be of more help

Answer (score 0):

If you can read each line into an array, loop through that array, and if index = 1 then add "\t" to the beginning of the line then adding it to the output String. Let's see if I can write up an example.

Let's say you already read each line into String[] lines.

```
String[] lines = readFromTextFileLineByLine();
String output = "";
int index = 0;
foreach(String line in lines)
{
    if(index==1)
        line = "\t" + line;
    output += line;
    index++;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Now for each paragraph in a richtextbox would be a bit different. Maybe you can split the text up by "\n", instead of reading from a file line by line, then running this to change your output. You will, however, run into the issue of where a new line occurs and how large the text box is width wise.