# EN_MAXTEXT message in richtextbox

Tags: c#, winapi

According to what is written on msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761684%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I should get EN_MAXTEXT message, when the number of characters to be inserted would exceed the width of the richTextBox, if it does not have the ES_AUTOHSCROLL style.
But it does not work for me.

I wrote this code:

```
    public class myRTB : RichTextBox
        {

            protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
            {
                if (m.Msg == (WM_REFLECT | WM_COMMAND))
                {
                    int code = (int)m.WParam;
                    code = (code >> 16) & 0xffff;  // convert to hiword   
                    if (code == EN_MAXTEXT)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("max text");
                    }
                }

                base.WndProc(ref m);
            }

            public const int WM_USER = 0x400;
            public const int WM_REFLECT = WM_USER + 0x1C00;
            public const int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;
            public const int EN_MAXTEXT = 0x0501;

        }
```

And I used this code to remove the ES_AUTOHSCROLL style:

```
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // get the style
                IntPtr style = GetWindowLongPtr32(myRTB1.Handle, GWL_STYLE);
                // remove the ES_AUTOHSCROLL style
                SetWindowLong32(myRTB1.Handle, GWL_STYLE, (int)style - ES_AUTOHSCROLL);
            }

            public const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
            public const int ES_AUTOHSCROLL = 0x0080;

            [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
            private static extern int SetWindowLong32(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]
            private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr32(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
```

Comment: Yes, that's documented behavior for an *Edit* control.  Works just fine if you derive from TextBox and override CreateParams to turn of the style bit.  But not for RTB, it doesn't care about having the style bit turned off, it scrolls anyway.  And doesn't generate the notification.  Not sure why you need this, the EN_VSCROLL notification works.

Comment: I wanted to create solution for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953670/indent-only-in-second-line-in-paragraph-in-rich-text-box-c), to create three paragraphs, the first and second contain only one row, and make indent in the second paragraph, and once I get a mesage from the first or second paragraph that the characters width larger than the width of the text box, I pass the extra text to the next paragraphg

Answer (score -1):

Remove the WM_REFLECT, it's irrelevant for C#.

Comment: No, this code works well when I type characters more than I set the **MaxLength** property, but does not work when the width of the characters I typed greater than text box width.